# SDCH Compression Library for C#

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I think SDCH Compression is better than gzip ,because it use Shared Dictionary(Reduce Dictionary Size) , I search SDCH Library for C#,but cannot find it ??

Comment: SDCH is an algorithm developed by google and has an RFC number 3284 (RFC is an number assigned by IEEE) and is also called VCDiff.  See following webpage for c# link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCDIFF.  Full spec can be found here : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3284

Comment: You can also use a shared dictionary with gzip (it's also supported by at least brotli, lzham, and lz4).

Comment: [This compression algorithm](https://github.com/Cyan4973/zstd#the-case-for-small-data-compression) explicitly supports Shared Dictionary compression, and provides a tool for dynamic creation of dictionaries.

It's written in C, so one will need to create C#<->C call wrappers to use it from within C# (see [this project](https://github.com/MiloszKrajewski/lz4net) for an example how to do it)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a C# library for SDCH. SDCH has gotten very little attention so far, and is not widely implemented.

jetNEXUS has some related tools for Windows servers: https://github.com/jetNEXUS

LinkedIn has posted about their implementation: https://engineering.linkedin.com/shared-dictionary-compression-http-linkedin

Like @nemequ said, you can use a dictionary with deflate. Cloudflare has a nice article about this: https://blog.cloudflare.com/improving-compression-with-preset-deflate-dictionary/